Quick Text not merging fields from related lookup Object
I'm using the standard Case object that has a custom field called: Case Financial Vendor which is a lookup relationship to the standard Account Object.
When trying to use Quick Text for merging fields from the related Account (or Case Financial Vendor), it won't merge anything or show any data.
This is the quick text and merge fields I'm using:


The merge field {!Case.Claim_Financial_Vendor__c} is working as expected, but then the ones with the __r are not. The fields are completed in the Account object so that's not the problem, they have data.


Currently , cross object merge fields are not supported in Salesforce Merge Language(SML) which powers Quick texts & Classic email templates.
There is a related idea posted for cross object merge fields.
A not so good workaround would be to create formula fields on Case object for the relevant fields on Account.
Quick text considerations
